# any shorter or faster alternative to bytes(str(some_variable), 'utf-8') in Python 3?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, type-conversion, arrays

For example, what's the best way to convert an integer like `5638463263` to its "byte stringified" version; `b'5638463263'`?

I can write `bytes(str(5638463263), 'utf-8')`, but that seems a bit verbose to me. Any shorthand or standard library function to do that better?

Comment: I think it's short enough.. Okay, i don't know if there is any shorter way.

Comment: @alKid Sure, it's not too terrible I guess, but considering how often this probably(?) needs to be done; I'm kinda surprised there is no equivalent `bytestr()` to `str()` in the standard library.

Comment: Why not make your own function?

Comment: Well, i never thought somebody would possibly say that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
str(5638463263).encode()
```

is shorter.

In Python 3.2 and later, `str.encode` uses `'utf-8'` as the default encoding.